# EXCEL and csv files: can Excel open a .$$$ file as a .csv file without using the Text import wizard?

Tags: excel, csv, wizard

I have lines of data in a text file that I want to open in **Excel**.

Each line represents different columns which are **separated by a comma**.

If my file's extension is CSV, the file association is showing the Excel icon on the file and Excel opens the file immediately, sorting rows and columns just fine.

If my file's extension is not **CSV**, say .**ABC**, then I need to use Excel the following way: File->Open then I need to use the **Text Import Wizard** and specify that the delimiter is a comma.

Is there a way to set up my computer (a register to edit?) so it forces Excel to open my .ABC file as a CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows you can change the program that Windows uses to open all files of the same type. In your case .ABC.
1) Right-click the file you want to change and then click Choose default program.

Click the program you want to use to open the file. In this case EXCEL.

If you want all files of that type to open in the same software program, select the Always use the selected program to open this kind of file check box, and then click OK.

If you want only that file to open in the software program this one time, clear the Always use the selected program to open this kind of file check box, and then click OK.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't solve the problem: in this case, Excel will consider the file as a text file. What I am looking for is a way to tell Excel: this file is to be treated the same way as a csv file.